# C# How to use Autofac to register httpcontextbase

Tags: c#

I use the following code to register httpcontextbase, but sometimes there are non null errors.

error message:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext

```
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
            if(HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                builder.Register(c =>
                    (new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) as HttpContextBase))
                    .As<HttpContextBase>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request)
                    .As<HttpRequestBase>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Response)
                    .As<HttpResponseBase>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Server)
                    .As<HttpServerUtilityBase>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Session)
                    .As<HttpSessionStateBase>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I don't know if it's because of multithreading? Can anyone help? be deeply grateful
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRROr.png)

Comment: Autofac has support for registering various types related to MVC via an extension module, `AutofacWebTypesModule`, have you tried using that rather than hand-coding it? https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/DA6737B.htm

Comment: @MartinCostello Thanks for your help. But I'm still not sure what you're talking about. You mean there's something wrong with my manual configuration? I need to use the method provided by Autofac to configure better, right?

Comment: Well I'm saying use a pre-written solution that's known to work, rather than hand-rolling your own that currently doesn't.